# Como salvo um array em linhas separadas no DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como posso enviar um textarea em que contem vários nomes, sendo um por linha, de modo que cada linha seja um registro no banco de dados? além também de cada linha receber o valor enviado por escola e turma, estou tentando assim, mas só vai um registro e no campo `nome` Está ficando em branco no DB, estou o usando código abaixo baseado na resposta do Pedro Augusto

Segue form:

```
  <form action="post.php" method="POST" id="usrform">
  Cidade: <input type="text" name="cidade"><br>     
  Escola: <input type="text" name="siem-id"><br>
  Nivel: <input type="text" name="nivel"><br>
  Turma: <input type="text" name="turma"><br>

  <br>
  Digite um nome por linha</br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="nome"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

> Estou fazendo assim:

```
    <?php 

 //RECEBE OS VALORES VIA POST
 $siem_id = $_POST["siem_id"];
 $cidade = $_POST["cidade"];
 $turma = $_POST["turma"];
 $nivel = $_POST["nivel"];
 $nome_post = $_POST["nome"];

 //QUEBRA A TEXTAREA POR "\n"
 $nome = explode("\n",$nome_post);

 //IMPRIMIR OS VALORES
 echo "Escola: ".$siem_id."<br>";
 echo "Cidade: ".$cidade."<br>";
 echo "Nivel: ".$nivel."<br>";
 echo "Turma: ".$turma."<br>";
 echo "Nome: <br>";
 for($i=0;$i<count($nome);$i++){
     $linha = $nome[$i];
     echo $linha."<br>";

    }

//conectando com o localhost - mysql
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$conexao)
    die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
//conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db("simrede",$conexao);
if (!$banco)
    die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());

//insere os dados
$query = "INSERT INTO `alunos` (`siem_id`, `cidade`, `nivel`, `turma`,  `nome`) 
VALUES ('$siem_id','$cidade', '$nivel', '$turma', '$linha')";

mysql_query($query,$conexao);

echo " <b>Cadastrados Com Sucesso!</b> ";
```

> Até imprime na tela os valores corretos, mas no banco o campo `nome` está ficando em branco

Comment: @PedroAugusto acredito que sejam coisas diferentes, no post que citou é enviado tudo como resgistro único, ou estou enganado? isso eu sei fazer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro vamos corrigir seu formulário:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="POST" id="usrform">
  Escola: <input type="text" name="escola">
  Turma: <input type="text" name="turma">
  <br>
  Digite um nome por linha
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="nomes"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Agora o arquivo que receberá o `POST`:

```
    <?php 

//conectando com o localhost - mysql
    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    if (!$conexao)
        die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
    //conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
    $banco = mysql_select_db("simrede",$conexao);
    if (!$banco)
        die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());


     //RECEBE OS VALORES VIA POST
     $siem_id = $_POST["siem_id"];
     $cidade = $_POST["cidade"];
     $turma = $_POST["turma"];
     $nivel = $_POST["nivel"];
     $nome_post = $_POST["nome"];

     //QUEBRA A TEXTAREA POR "\n"
     $nome = explode("\n",$nome_post);

     //IMPRIMIR OS VALORES
     echo "Escola: ".$siem_id."<br>";
     echo "Cidade: ".$cidade."<br>";
     echo "Nivel: ".$nivel."<br>";
     echo "Turma: ".$turma."<br>";
     echo "Nome: <br>";
     for($i=0;$i<count($nome);$i++){
         $linha = $nome[$i];
         echo $linha."<br>";
         //insere os dados
         $query = "INSERT INTO `alunos` (`siem_id`, `cidade`, `nivel`, `turma`,  `nome`) VALUES ('$siem_id','$cidade', '$nivel', '$turma', '$linha')";
         mysql_query($query,$conexao);
        }

     echo " <b>Cadastrados Com Sucesso!</b> ";
```

Comment: vou testar e te dou retorno, obrigado

Comment: Você não precisa dar explode por '\n' para inserir no banco, basta inserir no banco pela variável $nomes_post

Comment: Realmente poderia, mas de acordo com a pergunta: "de modo que cada linha seja um registro no banco de dados", por isso o explode.

Comment: Pedro apenas um registro é feito e o campo nomes está escrevendo "array"

Comment: Votei como duplicata, pois a resposta dada é a mesma coisa que a segunda resposta do post do fechamento (e é a solução adequada, fazer um explode e um loop); Na verdade a pergunta já começa errada, pois o problema não é o que foi descrito. A duvida real é "como salvo um array em linhas separadas do DB". (e o caminho mais simples é gerar uma sequencia de `VALUES`: no formato `INSERT INTO tabela (campos) VALUES (linha1), (linha2), (linha3)....` fazendo 1 insert só para várias linhas (no caso, só separando em mais de 1 insert quando o volume de dados da query ficar muito grande)

Comment: @MiguelSilva na resposta do você deve usar a query `INSERT INTO alunos ( escola, nivel , turma , nomes) 
VALUES ('$escola', '$nivel', '$turma', '$linha')`   (substituindo a variável $nomes pela variável $linha)

Comment: @gabriel.pelegrina, fiz conforme pediu, mas agora até imprime na tela os nomes dos alunos de textarea, mas no banco de dados o campo nome fica vazio

Comment: @Bacco, editei a pergunta conforme orientação e adicionei outras informações, obrigado

Comment: @MiguelSilva Olhe a resposta que editei. Tá certo, só falta executar a query e conectar ao banco

Comment: @PedroAugusto, desculpe não ter conseguido ainda, editei minha pergunta e adicionei o código completo que estou usando, não consigo encontrar erro, mas o campo `nome` está ficando vazio no DB.

Comment: Coloque a rotina para inserir dentro do laço for. Fora vc não vai conseguir pegar os valores

Comment: @MiguelSilva editado novamente a resposta

Comment: Perfeito! @PedroAugusto era isto, eu estava colocando fora do laço como você disse, vlw mesmo, Obrigado.